# How to move list item into folder in Sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, folder, list-item, jsom

I created a folder and have some item in this list. So now how can I move list item into folder using JSOM. I know user can drag/drop, but I want when user create a list is always move to folder automatically.

Answer (score 6):

Example: how to move list item into a folder via SharePoint JSOM API

```
/** 
 * Move ListItem
 * @param {SP.ListItem} list item 
 * @param {string} targetFolderUrl - server relative url of folder where listitem needs to be moved  
 */
function moveListItem(listItem,targetFolderUrl,success,error){
    var ctx = listItem.get_context();  
    ctx.load(listItem,['FileRef','FileDirRef']);
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(
      function(){
         var fileUrl = listItem.get_item('FileRef');
         var file = ctx.get_web().getFileByServerRelativeUrl(fileUrl);
         var targetfileUrl = fileUrl.replace(listItem.get_item('FileDirRef'),targetFolderUrl); 
         file.moveTo(targetfileUrl, SP.MoveOperations.overwrite);
         ctx.executeQueryAsync(success,error);
      },
      error);
}
```

**Usage**

```
var listTitle = "Requests";
var itemId = 1;
var targetFolderUrl = "/Lists/Requests/Archive";

var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
var item = list.getItemById(itemId);

moveListItem(item,targetFolderUrl,
    function(){
        console.log('List item has been moved');   
    },
    function(sender,args){
      console.log(args.get_message()); 
    }
)
```